# How to Split a String into Different Variables

Tags: java, parsing

Suppose I have the following code:

```
String s = "{U1,U2,U3},{U5,U7},{U4,U6,U8}";
```

How can I make this appear like it is below?

```
String s1 = {U1,U2,U3};
String s2 = {U5,U7};
String s3 = {U4,U6,U8};
```

The combination in `s` can be in any form.
s1, s2, s3 are different Strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following methods:

- [public int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to determine the index of the occurences like `"},{"`
- [public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) to extraxt the parts between the the found indexes.

See [example](http://ideone.com/DzH9PB):

```
  public static void parse(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
     String myString = "{U1,U2,U3},{U5,U7},{U4,U6,U8}";
     int begin = 0;
     int end = 0;
     String s1;
     while (end != -1){     
       end = myString.indexOf("},{", begin);

       if ((end < myString.length()) && ((begin < end)))
         s1 = myString.substring(begin, end + 1);
       else
         s1 = myString.substring(begin);

       begin = end + 2;
       System.out.println(s1);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Hi..I want each of the sub strings in different variable, like s1={U1,U2,U3}
s2={U5,U7}
s3={U4,U6,U8}

Comment: SO is not a give running code site, you need to show some effort, try to modify the code and ask if you face problems.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my code:

```
public class SplitString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s ="{U1,U2,U3},{U5,U7},{U4,U6,U8}";
        String[] splitted = s.split("},");

        // add the end brace for every entry except the last
        for (int i=0 ; i < splitted.length-1 ; i++) {
            splitted[i]=splitted[i] + "}";
        }

        // print out the string array
        for (int i=0; i< splitted.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println("String s"+i+" = "+splitted[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This splits every time it encounters the two characters `},`, puts that into the string array "splitted", then loops through the String array and adds a `}` at the end of every one except the last.

Output:

```
String s0 = {U1,U2,U3}
String s1 = {U5,U7}
String s2 = {U4,U6,U8}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `replace()` function replace `"{"` with `" "` and split based on `","`; take these values into array and sort the array. Now you can easily display whatever format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Split on `,}` combination of characters
. Following code is in C# . I don't know exact Java equivalent .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "{U1,U2,U3},{U5,U7},{U4,U6,U8}";

            string[] splitstring = Regex.Split(s,"},");
            // the string obtained are splitstring[0]= {U1,U2,U3 splitstring[1]={U5,U7    
            // splitstring[2]={U4,U6,U8}

           // Note only last string is not missing closing bracket so in a loop we append closing                 
          //  bracket to all strings except last string

            for (int i = 0; i < splitstring.Length; i++)
                if (i == splitstring.Length - 1)
                    continue;
                else
                    splitstring[i] = splitstring[i] + "}";

            foreach (string str in splitstring)
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide **Java** code when answering a **Java** question.

Comment: You can give an algorithm/idea/psuedocode If you don't know **Java**

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    String input = "{U1,U2,U3},{U5,U7},{U4,U6,U8}";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{[^\\}]*\\}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String s = matcher.group();
        System.out.format("%s\n", s);
    }
}
```